# example diagram of pullbacks and fiber products

Tags: category-theory, products, fiber-bundles

I am going through [Category Theory for Scientists](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-s996-category-theory-for-scientists-spring-2013/textbook/).  I am on section 2.5.1 **Pullbacks**.

I am having trouble visualizing a pullback.

Earlier in the book the author gives a nice diagram of an example of products of sets.

[image]

There is a similar diagram for coproducts of sets.

[image]

Is there some way to draw an example of a pullback or a fiber product?  Or is there some sort of example that would make pullbacks and fiber products easier to understand for someone coming from a programming background as opposed to a math background?  Or am I just thinking about this completely wrong?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to embed images into this post.  I would be grateful if someone could edit this post and change the links to images to actual embedded images.

Comment: Images embedded.

Comment: Thanks!  It looks much better now :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A pullback as just a certain subset of the product: those pairs $(a,b)$ on which the two given maps on coordinates agree, i.e. $f(a)=g(b)$.

This needs an explicit example, which I'll build on the lovely product diagram we already have available. So map $X=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}\to \{\text{even},\text{odd}\}$ in the obvious way, and $Y=\{\clubsuit,\diamondsuit,\heartsuit,\spadesuit\}$ by saying, for instance, the black suits $\clubsuit,\spadesuit$ are "even" and the others are "odd." Then the pullback becomes a subset of $X\times Y$ given by pairs $(n,s)$ where $n$ and $s$ have the same image in $\{\text{even},\text{odd}\}$. That is, the pullback has the twelve elements $\{(1,\heartsuit),(1,\diamondsuit),(3,\heartsuit),...,(5,\diamondsuit),(2,\spadesuit),(2,\clubsuit),...,(6,\clubsuit)\}$. If this begins to make some sense, see if you can compute

- the pullback of $X$ and $Y$ over the unique maps sending $X$ and $Y$ to a one-element set
- the pullback over the identity map $i:Y\to Y$ and any map $f:X\to Y$.

Comment: Would the pullback of $X$ and $Y$ over the unique maps sending $X$ and $Y$ to a one-element set be the entire product set of $X$ and $Y$?  All of the elements in $X \times Y$?

Comment: Yes, you've got it.